# Retrieve elements created by ngFor in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm implementing a lazy image loader in my Angular (5) app, and am curious how I can avoid having to call `setTimeout()` in my `ngAfterViewInit()`, if possible.

The relevant portions of the code are:

```
# component
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.workService.getCategories().then(workCategories => {
    this.workCategories = workCategories;
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.lazy-image'));
  }, 100);
}

# component template
<div *ngFor="let workCategory of workCategories">
  <h3>{{ workCategory.fields.name }}</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let workSample of workCategory.fields.workSamples">
    <img width="294" height="294" class="lazy-image" src="..." data-src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove `setTimeout()` the images array is always empty. [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview) should run after all of the child components have been created. I've also tried AfterContentInit, which behaves the same and AfterContentChecked, which crashed Chrome.

Is it possible to avoid setTimeout in this case?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are trying to grab direct access to the DOM nodes? Usually you want to do the least amount of direct access to dom as possible when using angular. For instance are you trying to setup the onload events for use in the lazy load?

Comment: I'm using an implementation of the IntersectionObserver to replace the original src with a data attribute containing the actual image url as they come into view.

Comment: Can we see what you do in `ngOnInit` and the part of the markup with the `lazy-image` element?

Comment: I've added the OnInit and a portion of the template markup. In a nutshell, I retrieve the work categories, then iterate over the samples for each category.

Comment: Just tried the changeDetectorRef strategy, and the array of images is still empty. I'm ok sticking with setTimeout, I was just curious if there was a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**This stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-issue-84qqqa) shows one method to get notified when the elements have been created with the `ngFor` directive. In the template, you assign a template reference variable `#lazyImage` to the `img` element:

```
<div *ngFor="let workCategory of workCategories">
  ...
  <div *ngFor="let workSample of workCategory.fields.workSamples">
    <img #lazyImage width="294" height="294" class="lazy-image" src="..." data-src="..." />
  </div>
</div>
```

In the code, `@ViewChildren("lazyImage")` is used to declare a `QueryList<ElementRef>` associated to these images. By subscribing to the `changes` event of the `Querylist` in `ngAfterViewInit`, you get notified when the elements are available. The HTML elements can then be retrieved from the `QueryList`:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, AfterViewInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChildren("lazyImage") lazyImages: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.lazyImages.changes.subscribe(() => {
      let images = this.lazyImages.toArray().map(x => x.nativeElement);
    });
  }
}
```

In cases where only the last created item is to be processed, the `QueryList.last` can be used:

```
    this.lazyImages.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.doSomethingOnLastImage(this.lazyImages.last);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try in the morning.

Comment: This works perfectly. I need to take another look at the docs for ViewChildren. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Thanks for this! In this scenario, is this 'waiting' for the last item to be rendered?

Comment: @DA - The `QueryList.changes` event is triggered every time the content of the `ngFor` loop changes, and the event handler is executed at that moment. If several elements are added at the same time, the event is triggered only once. A `console.log` statement in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-issue-84qqqa) shows that.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: and how can someone uses the value of `images`, in this example, outside the `subscribe` function?

Comment: @AZSH - This example does not show that; I assumed that the OP wanted to do something with the local variable `images`, as implied in his original code. However, you could declare a class property `public images: Array<HTMLElement>;` and set it in the callback: `this.images = this.lazyImages...`. That would make it available outside of the callback.

Comment: @ConnorsFan this does not work, unfortunately. the value of 'images' variable is `undefined`

Comment: @AZSH - We may continue that discussion in [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57029057/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `requesAnimationFrame` API.

Your problem is that even though Angular told the browser to render the images, they are not rendered yet, it takes some times for it to do so and update the DOM, that's why your array is empty.

The requestAnimationFrame API asks for the browser to tell you (via a callback method) when it's done with it's current tasks, when rendering is complete.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    //place your code here
  })
}
```

Comment: Hmm. That still results in an empty array for me.

Comment: Do you fetch the images urls in this component or pass them via an `@input`?

Comment: They are retrieved from a service call within the ngOnInit() in the component.

Comment: Then you are supposed to do the call to the `requestAnimationFrame` api once the data is loaded, not in the `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: Sorry, that method is still returning an empty array if I call it directly after the observable has returned a value.