# ngForm reference variable return undefined in ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular4-forms

I am trying to inject a form in a custom component and I am dynamically loading that component. For this case, while referencing the `ngForm` template variable, I am getting undefined:

```
<app-custom-component [template]="myTemplate">
    <ng-template #myTemplate>
        <form #myForm="ngForm">
            .....
        </form>
    </ng-template>
</app-custom-component>
```

Now in my `component.ts`

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.buyAmountForm.valueChanges.subscribe(values => this.validate()); //--> undefined, no valueChanges
}
```

If I remove the `ng-template`, everything works fine. Any workaround to get past this?

Comment: why you need template ???

Comment: Use `@ViewChildren('myForm')` and the `QueryList.changes` event, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227093/1009922).

Comment: any reason for negative voting... and why do I need template? Its because I have a reusable component and there is a template output there.....I think may be implementation is wrong or there may be a hack or workaround thats it

Answer (score 0):

access the descendants using `{descendants: true}`

```
@ViewChild('myForm', {descendants: true}) myForm;
```

Comment: tried that, getting this error: Argument of type '{ descendants: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'