# ngAfterViewInit() not quite as ready as I need it to be to update component's state

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm modifying a component (specifically a custom-rendered drop down list) to allow one to pass in a variable in the HTML and pre-select an item from the drop down.

`ngAfterViewInit()` seemed like the right place to grab the variable, and then update the view based on it.

I could not get it to work. It did everything *except* actually update the DOM to reflect the change.

I finally decided that maybe I should just brute-force it and instead of passing variables to functions within the angular I'll just grab the DOM object and click it:

```
...click()
```

Again, all the logic would fire, but the state in the DOM wouldn't actually update to reflect that.

I finally tried the "wrap it in a setTimeout" hack:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    ...click()
},100);
```

And...*that worked!*

Why?

Am I using the wrong hook? Or misunderstanding `ngAfterViewInit()`?

I noticed that I could put my call in `ngAfterViewChecked()` and it *would* work just fine there...but the problem, of course, is that hook is being constantly called, so my UI would get stuck in a loop if I place it there.

Is my having to use setTimeout a sign of something wrong elsewhere? (I assume it is, but not sure *what* that something wrong would be...)

Comment: is that specific element wrapped in an *ngIf at any given time?

Comment: In my click() example, yes, the actual element being 'clicked' is being rendered frominside an ngFor loop (looping through data to create each item of the drop down)

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta oops. Forgot to @ you ^

Comment: Can we see the markup? And the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: I can only suspect since there isn't any code. But it sounds like your hook isn't working due to a directive stopping it. You may be able to work around this by leaning on an Observable to handle the click event, the timeout you have can be applied with `.throttle()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve elements created by ngFor in ngAfterViewInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226233/retrieve-elements-created-by-ngfor-in-ngafterviewinit)

Comment: @ConnorsFan let me try. This is a complex mess at the moment (not my coding).

Comment: @Callat thanks. I'll look into that.